# JavaFX Choice Box localization

Tags: javafx, localization, box

I want to make a search in JavaFX:

At the moment I'm working with the Scene Builder and using a choice box to pick the category in which it will be looking for the word and a text field to write the word in. But I also want it to display the items in the choice box in the language I picked before logging into my program. I'm using ".properties" files (and the "internationalized string" option in the Scene Builder) for English and German and it works perfectly for buttons or labels but how can I make the choice box display the items in the right language? They only have a "fx:value" but no text, so I can't use that to select a string that I can use in the localization file.

Comment: IMO setting the item values through the controller will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This example should work as you want it to be.

```
<ChoiceBox>
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="%choice1" />
            <String fx:value="%choice2" />
            <String fx:value="%choice3" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Put your own localization keys in string fx:value attributes and give it a try.